# How do I insert an image instead of fillOval?

Tags: java

```java
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(ballPosX, ballPosY, 20, 20);
}
```

I want to insert an image here, i.e. "ball.png" image inside a "res" folder in Java project.

How can I do this keeping all of the ball functions, like ball position and size. Just need to paste an image instead of automatically drawn circle

Comment: Use the `drawImage(...)` method of the Graphics object. It allows you to specify the location and even scale the image if required. Also for custom painting you should override the `paintComponent()` method of your JPanel or JComponent.

Comment: [2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html#:~:text=This%20trail%20introduces%20you%20to,for%20beginners%20in%20computer%20graphics.); [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html); [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `g.drawImage()` method.

Example

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   g.drawImage(...);
}
```

You can adjust the arguments in the `g.drawImage()` to adjust the image drawn.

Comment: (1-) 1) that suggestion was already given an hour ago. There is no need to repeat the same advice 2) you should NOT override paint(). Again that suggestion was also given and can also be found in the tutorial links provided. Please read the tutorials.